# How can I show content following a read-more link using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a 'read more' link within a div. I would like the content after that link to be hidden on page load and displayed when the link is clicked. I would also like the link to either disappear, or change to 'less'.

The html is as follows:

```
<div class="widget-box">
//Text to be shown on page load
<a id="toggle">read more</a>
//Text to be toggled
</div>
```

- The content of the widget-box div is created using a WordPress text
  widget.
- I want to do this without adding extra html (divs and spans).
- The client needs control over where to place the #toggle link.

Thanks for your help.

Keith

Comment: What have you tried so far? Remember that we're here to help with what you're working on, not to do the work for you :)

Comment: Thanks Jamie, you're right. This is what I have so far:
 
    `<script>
    $(".toggle").parent().nextAll().hide();
    $(".toggle").click(function () {
    $(".toggle").parent().nextAll().toggle("slow");
    $(this).hide("slow");
    });
    </script>`

It does work, but the link has to be placed carefully at the end of a paragraph, as it won't shorten the paragraph it is currenty in.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [**small demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4pX4f/) to get you started. There are nicer ways to enhance this, for example using [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/text-overflow) to indicate the "more" part instead of "read more", or a nicer style on the "read more"; or another way of drawing attention to the "more", like a [call to action](http://larsjung.de/twinkle/), although that link is a plugin which is probably an overhead for a simple [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) or [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

HTML

```
<p class="widget-box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    <a href="#">read more</a>
    <span> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
</p>
```

CSS

```
p span {
    display:none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).next().show();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use jQuery Expander Plungin: http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/

It is the easiest one. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Rikudo. I've had a look at this plugin. Unfortunately, I need the client to be able to determine where the text is cut off and not have it set within the code.

Answer (score 2):

why not just create a another nested div?

```
<div class="widget-box">
//Text to be shown on page load
    <a class="toggle">read more</a>
    <div class="readmore-content">

    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.readmore-content { 
   display: none;

}
```

javascript/jquery

```
$(".toggle").click(function() {
   $(this).next('div').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Hi Uk. Thanks for your reply. That would be a great solution, unfortunately the content of the div is created by the client, so can't rely on extra html. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have so far:

```
<script>
jQuery(".toggle").parent().nextAll().hide();
jQuery(".toggle").click(function () {
jQuery(".toggle").parent().nextAll().toggle("slow");
jQuery(this).hide("slow");
});
</script>
```

It does work, but the link has to be placed carefully at the end of a paragraph, as it won't shorten the paragraph it is currently in.